# Preview printing on transparent material in Photoshop or Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, print-design, transparency, overprint

Been looking all over for a smart solution to this, but so far I haven't found anything.

I'm UV printing on transparent glass. As the UV printer does not print 'white' nor is there a white background (CYMK inks are used) I'm wondering how I can preview this setup in Illustrator or Photoshop?

So basically I need to remove the presence of white in the images I'm working with.

Best solution so far has been to use the blend mode Multiply, but that doesn't work in transparency preview or Simulate Overprint.

Really not sure what to test next, possibly remove the complete white channel? Color separate the plates and then stick them together on a transparent background?

Comment: I feel like you are confusing transparency in the file with the physically transparent ink and substrate. I presume you want to do this for simulation and/or preview but not submit files modified in this way? If that is the case, then try a PDF export with all transparency flattened/rendered and then use *that* as a multiply layer. In Iluustrator at least, you can place that pdf as a linked object that can be refreshed. In photoshop (some versions?) this link is not "live" though.

Comment: Photoshop has a Solidity setting for spot inks which kind if does what you are asking for. That's why that setting exists. But again, it's only for spot colors, not CMYK. I supposed you could create a multi-chanel spot file simply using Spot colors for CMY and K -- but that seems like an awful lot of work merely for a "preview" with isn't going guarantee accuracy.